# Division 10/100 gives 0

Tags: java, division

Dividing 10/100 in java gives me an answer of 0

```
    double s = 10/100;
    System.out.println(s);
```

I don't understand why that happens , can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: ... Which most people do in primary school but forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do a casting like this

```
 double s = (double)10/100;
System.out.println(s);
```

that'll do. Oh, and do as #SURESH ATTA suggests in the comment.